# how to delete files and folders

Tags: batch-file

How do I delete only files or folders that start with 2015 and 2014?

This is what I have so far, which it deletes all the files and folders under **`C:\Temp`** Folder

```
@TITLE = 
@ECHO ON

SET Folder="C:\Temp"

CD /D %folder%

FOR /F "Delims=" %%i IN ('DIR /B') DO (rmdir "%%i" /S/Q || DEL "%%i" /S/Q)

PAUSE
```

Comment: `del /f /s 2015*` followed by `del /f /s 2014*` perhaps? (when in C:/temp)

Comment: `dir` can work with Wildcards: `for ... ('dir /b 2014* 2015*') ...` Also `/s` could be useful.

Comment: @Stephan, - thanks it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `for` loops to walk through the directory tree; `for /R /D` enumerates all subdirectories recursively, and `for /R` returns the files:

```
pushd "C:\Temp"
for /R /D %%I in ("2014*" "2015*") do (
    rmdir /Q "%%~fI"
)
for /R %%I in ("2014*" "2015*") do (
    del /Q "%%~fI"
)
popd
```

Or you let `dir /B /S` return all items, files and directories, and parse its output with a `for /F` loop:

```
pushd "C:\Temp"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('
    dir /B /S "2014*" "2015*"
') do (
    2> nul rmdir /Q "%%~fI" || del /Q "%%~fI"
)
popd
```

The `2>nul` redirection avoids error messages to be returned by `rmdir`, if the current item is a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
@TITLE = 
@ECHO ON
SET Folder="C:\Temp"
CD /D %folder%
FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR /B') DO (
  SET FOLDER=%%I
  SET FOLDER=%FOLDER:~0,4%
  IF %FOLDER% == 2015 GOTO Delete
  IF %FOLDER% == 2014 GOTO Delete
  GOTO End
  :Delete
  RMDIR "%%I" /S /Q || DEL "%%I" /S /Q
  :End
)
PAUSE
```

%FOLDER:~0,4% means that you take the first 4 characters of the variable 'FOLDER'

Comment: `goto` and  Labels inside a `for` loop? This wouldn't run.